# append dropdown box selections to a textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction for what I am looking for... 
Basically, I would like to have 3-5 dropdown boxes (and maybe 2 textboxes) with each their own specific options. I would then like to append (or as excel would call it, CONCATENATE) the selected options into a string of text in a textbox after pressing a button (call it generate). I could define the string of text and where the options would reside.

Crude example;

**Selections:**

Dropdown 1  -  Dropdown 2 - Dropdown 3 - Textbox 1 - Textbox 2

**Output in textbox:**

Selection 1 - Selection 2 - Selection 3 - optional text - optional text

If anyone knows of an example that would best suit my needs that would be awesome so I can sort of figure it out... I have yet to come across one.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you would have to create a function that gathers all the values then formats them in the way you want.

An example of this would be:

```js
function generate(){
    var result = '';

    result += document.getElementById('drop1').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('drop2').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('drop3').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('text1').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('text2').value;

 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
}
generate();
```

```html
<select id="drop1" onchange="generate()">
    <option value="d1s1">D1 S1</option>
    <option value="d1s2">D1 S2</option>
</select>
<select id="drop2" onchange="generate()">
    <option value="d2s1">D2 S1</option>
    <option value="d2s2">D2 S2</option>
</select>
<select id="drop3" onchange="generate()">
    <option value="d3s1">D3 S1</option>
    <option value="d3s2">D3 S2</option>
</select>
<input id="text1" type="text" value="text1" onchange="generate()" onkeyup="generate()" />
<input id="text2" type="text" value="text2" onchange="generate()" onkeyup="generate()" />

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: This is perfect for me needs! Thank you very much :) I will definitely modify this up as I need :)

Where might I place function script? in header?

Comment: It's best practice to place it in its own separate file, then link to that file. Whichever way you do it (inline or file) you can either place the script in the header or in the body just before the </body> tag. If it's placed in the header, it will load before the page content, if in the body, after the page content. This is up to you and would depend on how big your site is and how much more you plan on adding to the function. I would suggest the JS in a separate file, then linked from the body.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson thus far! I have another issue... I would like to add multiple values to an option in the dropdown menu and "call" each individually into the string text in a different place... is that possible? I tried addeding different values to the option; `value2=x` and then using your `result += document.getElementById('drop1').value2 + ' - ';` to no luck ... any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Comment: It is possible, but you should try and stick with the default HTML attributes where you can. For what you want to do, you could add a delimiter to the value string, for example: `value="part1;part2"` then split the value on the `;` character. [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/PatTastic/9xf86jk2/1/). Depending on what you're making, you may want to have the value be an ID of an object, then pull in the object attributes.

Comment: I actually figured it out using datasets :) Say I wanted to make the string text in the javascript varresults each on a separate line (html code would be <br></br> for each value) how would I do that?
example;
`<br>value1</br>

<br>value2</br>

<br>value3</br>'